# Is there a special name for ring homomorphisms $f : R \rightarrow S$ with $f^*(C(R)) \subseteq C(S)$?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, terminology

*Edit. For some reason, I called the functor $F$ described below a full functor as opposed to a faithful functor. The problem has now been corrected.*

For any ring $R$, let $C(R)$ denote the center of $R$.

Is there a special name for either of the following?

1. Ring homomorphisms $f : R \rightarrow S$ such that $f^*(C(R)) \subseteq C(S).$
2. The category whose objects are rings whose arrows are the ring homomorphisms satisfying the above property.

*Motivation*. Let $\mathcal{R}$ denote the aforementioned category. Then there is an obvious faithful functor $F : \mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathrm{Ring},$ namely the inclusion. Furthermore, the center function gives rise to a functor $C : \mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathrm{CRing}$. I'd like to learn more about these functors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but I doubt that there is a special terminology for these homomorphisms. I would call them simply center-preserving homomorphisms of rings. While reading this, I think everyone will immediately understand what this means.

In the paper "On the limitations of sketches" by Michael Barr and Charles Wells it is discussed that the category of groups with center-preserving homomorphisms is not accessible. This is how they denote them in the abstract. In section 4, they write:

"By the category of groups with centers, we mean the category $\mathsf{GpCen}$ whose objects are groups and whose morphisms are those that preserve the center."

Of course nothing changes when you replace groups by monoids here, and "linear" monoids are exactly the rings.